# XAMPP Apache shows router page instead of Application

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, xampp

Pretty simple issue but cannot figure this out. I have a simple app in Windows 10 in the `xampp` folder. I have port forwarded using my router. However, when I put my public IP in the browser, I see the router's page instead of the App. The app works fine on the localhost. It is a `php` app. I have tried scores of changes to `httpd-conf` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` ..but it still doesn't work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/my-app"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/my-app">  
    Order allow,deny  
    Allow from all  
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I am a little confused with this ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com . I plan on accessing the app using just the IP Address, so I don't know what the ServerName should be. Is access to some folders blocked by anychance? Do I need to make changes in the `httpd-xampp.conf` file as well? A bit confusing this is. Some clarity is much appreciated.

P.S:- I don't want to map a domain. I am seeing the router's page..I want to see the index when accessing via the public IP..for now the public IP shows the router's page.

Comment: I believe those `##`-lines are commented out. in any case, the ServerName is just the hostname you've given to the system. You don't have to use it. If you're trying to access your host from internal network you just use the internal IP address. You can only use `<publicIP:port>` to access the system from the internal network if your router supports hairpin NAT i.e. NAT Loopback.

Comment: You need in the router to port-forward port 80 to your PC (instructions depend on the router's model). I would also suggest to block internet access to the router's login page.

Comment: @harrymc Did that..That's how when I enter my public IP ..I see the router's page.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I am looking to access my public IP from the internet. I have port-forwarded, but it shows my router's login page. It works for `localhost` but not for public IP.

Comment: Are you entering the public IP from within your local network? Most consumer routers do not support this correctly.

Comment: @harrymc I never even knew about this. Is that an issue as well? I will have to check and see that. Yes, I was checking on the same system. so within the network. Never had this issue before..though.

Comment: I think @harrymc is referring to the hairpin NAT as well (which concept I believe I myself learned from him recently :-) It's not clear what exactly the "this" is what you didn't know about. It can't be port forwarding as you've configured that. Please update your question with new info, don't provide it in comments, so all relevant info is available for any community member that wants to pitch in without digging it out from the comments.

Comment: Oki, that's what I was saying as well, with the explanation what your router needs to support it - hairpin NAT, also called NAT Loopback. I don't know your router or its configuration so I have no means of telling you how this can happen. I can only stress the advice @harrymc already gave - block the router management page access from the internet port entirely.

Comment: If you want to test the access to your server over the internet, you actually have to try it over the internet. For example you can create a hotspot on you phone and connect to that with laptop, then try to access the page. To help us help you, you could add to your question screenshots of your router's configuration, but take care to hide the public IP address.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Yes, I plan to do exactly, that. Thank a lot for your inputs.

Comment: Thank You for your input @harrymc

Comment: @harrymc It was what you said. It is accessible from outside of the network. I would have never figured it out. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary:

The problem here was that the router did not correctly implement NAT Loopback,
meaning a loop such as:
*PC -> router -> internet -> router -> PC*.

[NAT Loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback)
is not supported on many consumer routers.
The poster's router converted such access to an access to its login page.
It worked correctly when accessed from outside the local network.

Note: Opening the router's login page to the internet is a big security hole,
to be avoided.